# Wordpress - Convert query string as slash based URL

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks, pretty-urls

Is there a way to convert these query strings of a search result page template to pretty url?

my url structure is below:

https://example.com/properties/condos/?paged=0&listing_page_id=25884&type%5B%5D=condos&areas%5B%5D=toronto

I would like the output to be: https://example.com/properties/condos/areas/toronto or something similar.

Any suggestions?

TIA!

Comment: You need to add some details (plugins, custom post types, taxonomies, etc) of your current implementation to your question. Does [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/44037) give you some inspiration?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply choose from settings -> permalinks in wordpress admin dashboard. There are builtin url formats available as well ass you can make your own there.